# Node.JS async callback

Tags: node.js, callback, asynccallback, node-async

I have been using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to manage my code flow and it's indeed a very powerful lib. However, as the code grows bigger and logical flow become more complex, I run into a problem with too many async_callback to manage. Some pseudo code to demo the issue as below

```
async.auto({
   getjobs:function(cb){},
   loopjobs:['getjobs']{
      async.map(jobs,dojob(job, cb_map),cb); 
   },
}, function(err, result) {
    //handle
}); 

function dojob(job, callback) {
    async.auto({
        step1:function(cb){},
        step2:['step1', function(cb) {}],
        step3:['step1', function(cb) {
           moreloops(params, cb);
        }]
    }, callback)
}

function moreloops(params, cb) {
    async.map(params, doloop(param, cb_map), cb);
}

function dbloop(param, cb) {
    //dosomething
    cb();
}
```

In this flow, a combination of `loops`, `sequential`, `parallel` and `conditional` async callback is being used due to the need of the business logic. It become quite difficult to troubleshoot if any function is not returning a callback for any reason. I tried to debug using logging framework but obviously it's not very efficient due to the asynchronous nature of node.js.

Is there any good way to

1. Improve the flow in coding
2. Identify in which function the flow stops.

Thanks!

Comment: Abandon callbacks and move to promises? Is that an option ?

Comment: Use promises.  Much each to manage flow of control and errors.

Comment: I think `events` are quite useful too, in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to improve debugging

1. Use [vasync module](https://github.com/davepacheco/node-vasync) It's like async but with better debugging
2. vasync may not have all the tools you need so [promisify (bluebird)](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) all callbacks and use promises so that functions will return at least `.then` and `.catch`

For example, in request module:

```
var request = require('request');
function makeRequest(cb) {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
        cb(err, body);
    });
}
```

becomes

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);

function makeRequest(cb) {
    request(url)
        .then(function(response) {
            var body = response.body;
            cb(null, body);
        })
        .catch(cb);
}
```

Just pass all the success in `.then` and errors in `.catch` and pass errors back to the the highest level.